# fancybox and worldpay

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, worldpay

I am working with a website today, that requires me to integrate worldpay into, via a buy now button, the budget does not allow for a huge amount of design work, so I am thinking of integrating the world pay steps into a nice overlay, and then just having nicely styled forms.

My problem is that alot of the javascript that worldpay provides to use it's forms uses the `open()` function. This closes fancybox and opens the next step in new tab, is there a way around this? Maybe another function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could "enjoy" editing the worldpay templates and change the javascript to load the next page via ajax and your fancybox could watch that and change it's content.

another solution is to use an iframe and style it so that it looks seamless. you might still have to remove headers and footers from the worldpay themes for it to work.

Comment: I am currently "enjoying" editing the worldpay templates...don't think I have every seen source code as bad! Do you have experience of using these examples? I have another question that maybe you could help with.

Comment: I could help, just link to the question from here. But the perfect solution is for your client to use sagepay or stripe instead. but usually the move to worldpay is because they are penny pinching. Charge something exorbitant for worldpay designs and they quickly drop their demands or more to another gateway.

Comment: Many thanks Joseph, he is the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8355880/stiching-worldpay-examples-together