# stiching worldpay examples together

Tags: php, javascript, html, forms, worldpay

Hello I am working with worldpay at the moment, I am want to stich a few of the worldpay integration examples together, I have been told it is possible but I personally cannot see how.

The basics behind the e-commerce of the site, if the users selects a product, some extra options, and delivery region, they then click buy. This is much like this example from worldpay http://www.worldpay.com/support/kb/bg/examples/example_0/jr_example0.3.html, when the user clicks purchase I then want to send them to this page, http://www.worldpay.com/support/kb/bg/examples/example_0/jr_example0.5.html then finally take them to worldpay hosted checkout page.

Is this possible? Where do I submit the forms too? How do I pass what has been purchased through my form procedures?

Comment: you should probably not be doing any product selection from worldpay, worldpay can probably be given the line items, and on the callback end just check that form data hasn't been hacked. which shopping cart are you implementing this for?

Comment: there is not cart, they just select a product and hit buy now

Comment: just sending the client to the invoice should do the trick? you should avoid doing as much work in worldpay as possible, worldpay is just to confirm payment and create a callback or email for the right department.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible.

You submit the form to https://secure-test.worldpay.com/wcc/purchase

To pass data from one form to the next

1 Set your form like this

```
<form action="page2.php" method="POST">
```

2 On page two get the date from $_POST

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value)
```